# Jersey split payload

Tags: java, jersey

I am wondering, if it is possible to split the payload in a request which is consumed by Jersey. I want to achieve this:

```
@PUT
@Path("/endpoint")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response method(long[] vals1, long[] vals2) {
    // Do something...
}
```

The data I would send is structured as follows:

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]
```

Is this possible or do I have to send a `Map`-like object and update the signature of the `method` accordingly to a `Set<String, List<Long>>`?

```
{ "vals1": [1,2,3], "vals2": [3,4,5] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object with both arrays inside and configure jersey to parse json using jackson. Then you should send the request with a json body:

```
{
"vals1": [1,2,3],
"vals2": [4,5,6]
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that. But is this also possible without defining a custom object/using a `Map`?

Comment: No, it's not, you'll get an error that says something like: contains multiple parameters with no annotation. Unable to resolve the injection source.

Comment: Ok thank you. I was suspecting that this shouldn't be possible